# Adding name parameter to protractor config file

Tags: protractor, browserstack

I want to add name parameter to my protractor config file , so that when my test runs on browserstack it can show the title of the spec or suite.

Tried below but did not help. Can some one suggest a better alternative.

```
    name: `specs || undefined`,
```

Comment: Does it normally output the test names in local environment?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I want to see the same on Browserstack

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working configuration file with *name* capability

```
exports.config = {
  'specs': [ '../specs/single.js' ],
  'browserstackUser': process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME || 'BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME',
  'browserstackKey': process.env.BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY || 'BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY',

  'capabilities': {
    'name': 'single_test',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'browserstack.debug': 'true'
  }
};
```

You may refer a sample project with similar configuration on the following link: https://github.com/browserstack/protractor-browserstack/blob/master/conf/single.conf.js